# Converting a SQL query to Active Record in Rails 4

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Here are my two models

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :phone
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Here is the schema for the tables

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131119231249) do

create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
t.string   "username"
t.string   "ipaddy"
t.text     "pcomments"
t.string   "company"
t.string   "calltype"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "pnumber"
t.string   "source"
end

create_table "phones", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "pnumber"
t.text     "mrcomment"
t.integer  "ccount"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
end
```

Here is the raw SQL that works

```
SELECT phones.ccount ,
   comments.*
   FROM phones
   INNER JOIN comments
   ON phones.pnumber = comments.pnumber;
```

When I run the following in my controller

```
    @phones = Phone.select("phones.ccount, comments.*").joins(:comments).where(:comments => {comments.pnumber => phones.pnumber})
```

I get the following error

```
undefined local variable or method `comments' for #<FrontPageController:0x00000003c56c70>
```

Any help on what the active record statement should like would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using the select() erroneously. Have you read the docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select ?

from docs: "Second: Modifies the SELECT statement for the query so that only certain fields are retrieved:"

The query's syntax should more look like (using a standard example):

```
l = Location.where(["id = ?", id]).select("name, website, city").first.
```